# Why does SVN keep deleting this file on checkout?

Tags: eclipse, svn

My team uses Eclipse Juno and the SVN plugin to interact with the Subversion data store. When I checkout a branch a configuration file is always deleted. Here is the end of the console log for one instance:

```
    A   C:/Projects/mytarget.283993/.settings
    A   C:/Projects/mytarget.283993/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
    A   C:/Projects/mytarget.283993/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
    A   C:/Projects/mytarget.283993/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component
     U  C:/Projects/mytarget.283993
    Checked out revision 6583.
delete --force C:/Projects/mytarget.283993/web/WEB-INF/classes/ApplicationResources.properties
    D         C:/Projects/mytarget.283993/web/WEB-INF/classes/ApplicationResources.properties
```

**Is it something my team wrote?  Then where do I locate the checkout script?**

**Or is it something about this file that SVN objects to?**

My SVN files are:

```
Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.0.0
Subversion client adapter 1.8.6
Subversion JavaHL 1.7.10
Subversion Revision Graph 1.1.1
SVN Team Provider Core 1.8.22
```

Thanks for answers,
Jerome.

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationResources.properties` is *some* metadata-file (local, specific to every workplace most probably), which

- *You* have versioned in repository
- *Rest of team* added into ignore-pattern

thus - every update to revision, there this file is missing, removes file from your WC (as expected). Unversion and ignore this file - it **must not** be shared across team

Comment: This ApplicationResources.properties file is a config file read when my app server starts. All of my team wants the file, and it is deployed by us onto the test and production servers with the server code. It is just as valid to us as web.xml or any Java file we're using.  That said, what in particular is telling SVN to download the file and then delete it from the target directory?  If I learn that then I can undo this action, I think.  In SVN, its directory (WEB-INF/classes) has an svn:ignore but don't directly or indirectly refer to that file.